# Function not skipping between questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a questionnaire where I can skip between questions. When I open the html file in opera or chrome, I just see 1 and 2. When I press them, nothing happens. The code is below. Any help would be appreciated

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
   var linkedDiv = $(this).data('linkedto')
   $('div.container').parent('div').hide();
   $(linkedDiv).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/quiz.js"></script>

<link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">

<p class="btn" data-linkedto="#b">1</p>
<p class="btn" data-linkedto="#bDate">2</p>
<div id="b" style="display:none" ;>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Name of school: <br> class: <br>Today's Date: </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bDate" style="display:none" ;>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="bday">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Are you executing your jQuery before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: @Alyssa In the snippet it appears to be working as intended?

Comment: Try to move `<script src="js/quiz.js"></script>` to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I am opening the html file in a browser, not using a console @j08691

Comment: I now realise that @cmprogram, but it still doesn't work when I load the html file in opera

Comment: @Alyssa Your browser *has its own console*. Press F12 to open the dev tools and go to the console tab. You should familiarize yourself with basic debugging techniques. And please answer my second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is missing [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). This is necessary as you're trying to bind a click handler before jQuery knows about your DOM elements.

An alternative approach would be to place the JS before hand the closing body element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
       var linkedDiv = $(this).data('linkedto')
       $('div.container').parent('div').hide();
       $(linkedDiv).show();
    });
});
```

This means jQuery tries to select an element with class btn (`$('.btn')`) which is not present during the execution time. document ready delegates the execution to the point where your DOM is rendered and accessible by jQuery.

#### Fixed Example

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn').click(function(){
   var linkedDiv = $(this).data('linkedto')
   $('div.container').parent('div').hide();
   $(linkedDiv).show();
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/quiz.js"></script>

<link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">

<p class="btn" data-linkedto="#b">1</p>
<p class="btn" data-linkedto="#bDate">2</p>
<div id="b" style="display:none" ;>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Name of school: <br> class: <br>Today's Date: </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bDate" style="display:none" ;>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="bday">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```